# Angular 6 - Modifying Add Method to do Update on View

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am making changes to a list of data which is displayed on app.component.html

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let data of DataSource"> 
        {{ data.id }} - {{data.title}} 
</li>
</ul>
```

I have managed to push a new data row like this:

```
  create() {
    const newPostId = this.postId + 1;
    this.apiService.create(newPostId, this.postTitle, this.postText).subscribe(result => {
      const newId = result['id'];
      this.retrieveData.push({id: newId, title: this.postTitle});
      this.dataCount = this.dataCount + 1;
    }, error => console.log('There was an error: ', error));
  }
```

This works fine and adds a new row to the end of the data list.

My question is:

How do I modify my create() method to update a current and display the changes on the app.component.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to find the item in the array whose id matches the one you are updating and replace it with the new one, you would do something like:

```
this.apiService.update(...).subscribe(result => {
  const newId: number = result['id'];
  const currentItemIndex = this.retrieveData.findIndex((item: {id: number}) => item.id === newId);
  if (currentItemIndex > -1) {
      // replace the current item with the new one
      this.retrieveData.splice(currentItemIndex, 1, {id: newId, title: this.postTitle});
  } else {
     // TODO: if it wasnt there to being with, is this an error?
  }
}, error => console.log('There was an error: ', error))
```